# Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date error

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I'm getting this error adding data to tables and I couldn't find the exact reason. Can you help me? In below you can see the script of my table and the data I am trying to add.(In SSMS 18)

TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(200),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(200),
    EMAIL VARCHAR(200),
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(10),
    USER_TYPE_ID TINYINT,
    BIRTHDAY DATE,
    GENDER CHAR(5),
    LOGIN_WITH_ID TINYINT,
    PHONE CHAR(12),
    RECEIVE_COUPON INT,
    COUNTRY_ID INT,
    CREATED DATETIME,
    MODIFIED DATETIME,
    STATUS TINYINT,
    LANGUAGE_ID INT

    CONSTRAINT FK_USER_TYPE 
        FOREIGN KEY(USER_TYPE_ID) REFERENCES USER_TYPE(ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_LOGIN_WITH 
        FOREIGN KEY(LOGIN_WITH_ID) REFERENCES LOGIN_WITH(ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_COUNTRY_2 
        FOREIGN KEY(COUNTRY_ID) REFERENCES COUNTRIES(ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_LANGUAGE_2 
        FOREIGN KEY(LANGUAGE_ID) REFERENCES LANGUAGE(ID)
)
```

Inserting data:

```
INSERT INTO USERS (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD, USER_TYPE_ID, BIRTHDAY, GENDER, LOGIN_WITH_ID, PHONE, RECEIVE_COUPON, COUNTRY_ID, CREATED, MODIFIED, STATUS, LANGUAGE_ID) 
VALUES (123451, 'Simon', 'Walsh', 'brimmere@state.gov', 'kzde5577', 1, 21642, 'Male', 1, 17688652138, 1, 383, 37748, 42009, 0, 15)
```

Comment: Data type `int` can't be [implicitly converted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#implicit-and-explicit-conversion) to `date`? You need to use `DATEADD()` instead.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. What about the message don't you understand?

Comment: Your column `BIRTDAY` is of type `DATE` - so you should be inserting something like `1989-11-23` or some other **valid** date string literal - what is `21642` supposed to be???

Answer (score 0):

In your table "**USERS**" the Columns (**BIRTHDAY**-> DATE,**CREATED & MODIFIED** -> DATETIME) data types are mismatched with your table Insertion Statement.

So, this is the reason for this "Operand type Clash Error".